# transparent "symlink + binary patch"

Tags: filesystems, patch

I have a project where I am collecting and organizing mp3 files from a long-running radio show. Being from various origins and sources, the naming conventions and ID2/3 tags are all over the place.

I want to create a set of canonicalized files. To that end, I've taken to preserving the directory structure and filenames, and symlinking that to a standardized directory structure and filename. That way, I can easily tell what I have and what I'm missing, but yet also know when I encounter a show "in the wild" that I already have.

But there remains the problem of the ID2/3 tags. I want to standardize them too, but I can't do so without changing the source mp3.

I was thinking that, in an ideal world, I update a copy of the mp3 file, create a binary patch against the original, and then somehow create a symlink of that patch, plus the original file, to create a new, canonicalized virtual file that's transparent to the file system.

Is there any similar solution out there for this problem?

Comment: `ID2/3` tags are just the kind of things you would like to put in a database.  mongo, redis, sqlite, can be anything, you just want one table for the original one and a second table for the updated ones.  You then just add the path of the original mp3 (or the softlink) as a unique field.

Comment: @grochmal Then I have to make an interface to database, instead of just using command line tools like `mediainfo`? Doesn't seem to fit the bill -- I could just manage a plain text file.

Comment: You might look into using a container, eg matroska, mp4, ogm. These containers can hold the original mp3 encoded data, but have supplementary information. You would still have to copy the data though.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a FUSE filesystem, but I can't find an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at some fuse filesystems, and the simplest to get working is **concatfs** by Peter Schlaile. If nothing else it would be good place to start, as the C code implementation is small and self-contained.

Basically, for any file *A* you want to "symlink" to, in some arbitrary source directory *S* you create a file *B* that contains just the id3 tag info (version 2) you want, then a magic file *C* with a filename that contains the characters "-concat-" somewhere. This file *C* contains, in order, the names *B* and *A*.

When you run the concatfs program you specify the source directory *S* and a second arbitrary mountpoint directory *M*. In *M* you will see all the same files as in *S*, but when you read file *C* you will get a concatenation of *B* and *A*, i.e. your new tags followed by the real mp3 data. Obviously, only the magic files really need to be in *S*, as you can use absolute or relative paths in a magic file.

This is not perfect because if your *A* file contains id3v2 tags (at the start of the file) they will be added to those in your *B* file. Also, id3v1 tags (at the end of the file) will still be there.  However with some C coding it should be possible to suppress the beginning and end of *A*.  Also, it is trivial to change the magic string "-concat-".

Here are the commands I used to test concatfs. Install the `fuse-devel` package so that you can compile the code. The rest does not need you to be root.
[Download](https://github.com/schlaile/concatfs/archive/master.zip) and unzip the sources and compile them:

```
cd concatfs
gcc -Wall src/concatfs.c $(pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs) -o concatfs
```

Create the 2 directories, start the command, and copy some mp3 file to play with, removing any tags in it:

```
mkdir -p ~/myfuse/src ~/myfuse/mnt
./concatfs ~/myfuse/src ~/myfuse/mnt  # runs in background
cd ~/myfuse/src
cp ....sometestfile.mp3 try.mp3
id3v2 --delete-v1 try.mp3
id3v2 --delete-v2 try.mp3
id3info try.mp3
```

Create the dummy file, the magic file, and add some id3v2 tags to the dummy file:

```
echo -e 'dummy.mp3\ntry.mp3' > try.mp3-concat-.mp3
> dummy.mp3
id3v2 -2 -c 'my description:my comment' -a  'my artist' -A 'my album' -y '2010' -T 1/2  dummy.mp3
hexdump -C dummy.mp3 
ls -l
```

Look in the second directory to find the same files, but the size and contents of the magic file is the concatenation of the two files:

```
ls ../mnt/ -l
cat ../mnt/try.mp3-concat-.mp3 | wc -c
id3info ../mnt/try.mp3-concat-.mp3
mediainfo ../mnt/try.mp3-concat-.mp3
```

When you kill the program you may need to clean the mount:

```
fusermount -u ~/myfuse
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my case for why a database could be a good solution:

- Because the SQL query language is flexible, it allows you to associate old and new filenames with a `id_tag` via a declarative addressing system.
- It's able to be extended to provide additional uses - as an example I've added a category tag in the script below.
- if using SQLite it can be used from the command line and it produces STDOUT which can be piped, redirected etc.

My example is based on the idea that each show is a identified by a unique record, in a single table (simpler than multiple tables) all info about that radio show will be contained in a record in that table
using `sqlite`

#### install sqlite

```
apt-get install sqlite3
```

or use `yum`, `pacman`, build from source or whatever

cd into your database directory and create script

file: `music_db.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f music_db ]
then
    rm -v music_db
fi

sqlite3 music_db << 'EOF'
    create table radio_shows(
        original_filename text,
        new_filename      text,
        id_tag            text,
        category_tags     text
    );
EOF

sqlite3 music_db << 'EOF'
    insert into radio_shows 
    (original_filename, new_filename, id_tag, category_tags) values
    ('first_show-001', 'first_show-001--new_naming_scheme', 'id_tag aaa', 'favourite_shows'),
    ('first_show-002', 'first_show-002--new_naming_scheme', 'id_tag aab', 'favourite_shows'),
    ('first_show-003', 'first_show-003--new_naming_scheme', 'id_tag aac', 'crap_shows'),
    ('first_show-004', 'first_show-004--new_naming_scheme', 'id_tag aad', 'favourite_shows');
EOF
```

Then use from the command line:
e.g. add a new show

```
% sqlite3 music_db <<EOF
insert into radio_shows                  
(new_filename, id_tag, category_tags) values 
('a_new_show', 'xyz_123', 'good_show'); 
EOF
```

retrieve the show (at a later date) and print to STDOUT

```
% sqlite3 music_db <<EOF
select new_filename, id_tag
from radio_shows
where category_tags = "good_show";
EOF
```

result

```
a_new_show|xyz_123
```

Comment: I don't see how this beats a well-managed text file and grep : S

Comment: I agree that there is alot of value to being able to simply open the file and view its contents with an editor or a pager, and use standard UNIX utilities , especially if you want to use command substitution to feed the file and tag into another program like a player or something. I would only got to the trouble of the DB when dealing with storage, retrieval and management can't be done simply with flat files